# Add sort option to the table when the column header is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

[image: My grid table]

Add sort option to the table when the column header is clicked, Post code for it.

```
colNames: ['Incident key', 'Date', 'State', 'Incident no', 'FF death', 'OTH death', 'Property Loss', 'Cont Loss', 'Fire Cause'],
        colModel :[ 
        {
            name:'a.INC_KEY', 
            index:'a.INC_KEY',
            width: 220,
            hidden: true,
            editrules: {
                edithidden:true
            },
            searchoptions: {
                sopt: ['eq', 'ne','cn']
            }
        }, 

        {
            name:'a.INC_DATE', 
            index:'a.INC_DATE',
            width: 100,
            searchoptions: {
                sopt: ['eq', 'ne','cn']
            }
        }, 

        {
            name:'a.INC_NO', 
            index:'a.INC_NO',
            width: 100,
            searchoptions: {
                sopt: ['eq', 'ne','cn']
            }
        }, 

        {
            name:'a.STATE', 
            index:'a.STATE',
            width: 100,
            searchoptions: {
                sopt: ['eq', 'ne','cn']
            }
        }, 

        {
            name:'a.FF_DEATH', 
            index:'a.FF_DEATH',
            width: 80,
            searchoptions: {
                sopt: ['eq', 'ne','cn']
            }
        }, 

        {
            name:'a.OTH_DEATH', 
            index:'a.OTH_DEATH',
            width:80,
            searchoptions: {
                sopt: ['eq', 'ne','cn']
            }
        },

        {
            name:'a.PROP_LOSS', 
            index:'a.PROP_LOSS',
            width: 80,
            searchoptions: {
                sopt: ['eq', 'ne','cn']
            }
        },

        {
            name:'a.CONT_LOSS', 
            index:'a.CONT_LOSS',
            width: 80,
            searchoptions: {
                sopt: ['eq', 'ne','cn']
            }
        },

        {
            name:'a.CAUSE_CODE_DESC', 
            index:'a.CAUSE_CODE_DESC',
            width: 240,
            searchoptions: {
                sopt: ['eq', 'ne','cn']
            }
        },
        ],
        pager: '#pager',
        rowNum: 500,
        rowList:[500,100,20],
        sortname: 'INC_KEY',
        sortorder: 'desc',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortable: true,
        height: 400,
        width: 800, 
        shrinkToFit: false,
        gridview: true,
        caption: 'Reports'
    });

    jQuery("#list1").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{
        edit:false,
        add:false,
        del:false
    });
```

Comment: You do realize that this isn't a "write this code for me" site, right?

Comment: how to sort the content of column tradyblix, want to sort all columns when the column header is clicked

Comment: not so.., just help out to write @alexandernst

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using JQGrid, I think this code will help you

```
jQuery(function() {
        $("#list1").jqGrid({
            url:'file1.php',
            datatype: 'json',
            colNames:['Member Name','Administrstor Name' ,'Time', 'Status','Mobile'],
            colModel :[ 
                {name:'memberid', index:'memberid',align:'left',width: 142,searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne','cn']}}, 
                {name:'adminid', index:'adminid',align:'left',search: false,width: 142}, 
                {name:'sendon', index:'senton',width: 167,searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne','cn']}}, 
                {name:'status', index:'status',width: 117,search: false},
                {name:'mobile', index:'mobile',width: 162,search: false}
            ],
            pager: '#pager',
            rowNum: 5,
            rowList:[5,10],
            sortname: 'id',
            sortorder: 'desc',
            viewrecords: true,
            height: 'auto',
            width: 790, 
            shrinkToFit: false,
            rownumbers: true,
            gridview: true,
            caption: 'Message Sent Today'
        });
        jQuery("#list1").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});

    });
```

Comment: The above code will generate a JQGrid, and make all column header to do sorting.

Answer (score 1):

There are several plugins available for this,One among them is data tables,(ut requires just 2 lines of coding! and is most suitable for you)

The following is an example link,

http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/multi_col_sort.html

Answer (score 1):

You should use the value from `name` property of some column as the value of `sortname`. You current code use `sortname: 'INC_KEY'`, but there are no column in the `colModel` with the corresponding name. You should use `sortname: 'a.INC_KEY'` instead.

Moreover I recommend you to rename all the columns to have no `.` in the names. You should understand that the `name` property will be used to construct some `id` values in the grid and will be used in [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). Usage of names without any special characters will reduce the risk that you will have some strange side effects and some features of jqGrid will works not like expected. If you have remote `datatype` (`"json"` or `"xml"`) you can use `index` which has `a.` prefix, but you should not have such prefix in the `name` property.